# How to use use appropriate expression trees to handle different scenarios

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a scenario in which to process different csv files to a common format. My CSV files contain the student ids, names and scores of different students. But the distribution of data in the csv files differs from file to file. For eg, in the first csv file, student id, first name, last name, scores out of hundred in Biology, Chemistry, Physics, English, French, Mathematics are distributed as follows:

Distribution type 1:

001, John, Doe, 098, 099, 095, 088, 075, 096

002, Jane, Doe, 099, 095, 096, 085, 095, 099

In yet another csv file, the same data is distributed as Student first name, last name, student id, scores out of 100 in English and French, scores of 50 in Geometry and Algebra, and lastly, scores out of 100 in Chemistry, Biology and Physics, like the following:

Distribution type 2:

John, Doe, 001, 088, 075, 048, 048, 099, 098, 095

Jane, Doe, 002, 085, 095, 050, 049, 095, 099, 096

The output for both the above distributions should be:

student id [space] student first name [space] student last name [space] % of scores in languages (i.e., English + French) [space] % of scores in mathematics (Algebra + Geometry) [space] % of scores in sciences (Physics + Chemistry + Biology)

So for both the above distributions, the output would be

001 John Doe 081 096 097

002 Jane Doe 090 099 097

To transform the input in the first case, the code would be the following:

```
    string csv1 = @"D:\MyPath\Distribution1.csv";
    string outputPath = @"D:\MyPath\OutputFile.txt";
    string line = string.Empty;
    string outputLine = string.Empty;
    string[] data = null;


    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csv1)) {

        while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
            line = sr.ReadLine();                   
            data = line.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.None);

            outputLine = data[0] + " "
                + data[1] + " " + data[2] + " "
                + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[6]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[7])) * 100)/200) + " "
                + data[8] + " "
                + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[3]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[4]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[5])) * 100) / 300);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputPath)) {
                sw.WriteLine(outputLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

To process the second csv file, it would be the following:

```
    string csv2 = @"D:\MyPath\Distributio21.csv";
    string outputPath = @"D:\MyPath\OutputFile.txt";
    string line = string.Empty;
    string outputLine = string.Empty;
    string[] data = null;


    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csv2)) {

        while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
            line = sr.ReadLine();                   
            data = line.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.None);

            outputLine = data[2] + " "
                + data[0] + " " + data[1] + " "
                + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[3]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[4])) * 100)/200) + " "
                + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[5]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[6])) * 100)/100) + " "
                + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[7]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[9])) * 100) / 300);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputPath)) {
                sw.WriteLine(outputLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code to generate outputLine is obviously not ideal. I wish to replace them with expression trees. Seeking inputs on how to replace the following code snippets:

```
    outputLine = data[2] + " "
        + data[0] + " " + data[1] + " "
        + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[3]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[4])) * 100)/200) + " "
        + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[5]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[6])) * 100)/100) + " "
        + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[7]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[8]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[9])) * 100) / 300);
```

and

```
    outputLine = data[0] + " "
        + data[1] + " " + data[2] + " "
        + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[6]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[7])) * 100)/200) + " "
        + data[8] + " "
        + Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToInt32(data[3]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[4]) + Convert.ToInt32(data[5])) * 100) / 300);
```

with expression trees.

Please also let me know how the expression trees may be associated with the the respective input files. I wish to invoke the appropriate expression tree corresponding to the file type.

Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why expression trees? What made you think they are the right solution here?

Comment: Also, do you already have some way of finding out which format does a file have? Or do you have to guess that?

Comment: If something other than expression trees can be associated with each distinct input distribution, and can be invoked for one, please let me know. And yes, the distribution is fixed for a given input file name. That doesn't need to be guessed.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with your code is that there is no [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). What you should do is to split your code into three parts:

1. One that reads the input file and produces a collection of objects as output.
2. One that combines the scores, outputting collection of different objects.
3. One that writes combined scores to a file.

In your case, doing that could look something like this:

```
class StudentScores1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Biology { get; set; }
    public int Chemistry { get; set; }
    public int Physics { get; set; }
    public int English { get; set; }
    public int French { get; set; }
    public int Mathematics { get; set; }
}

class CombinedScores
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Languages { get; set; }
    public int Mathematics { get; set; }
    public int Sciences { get; set; }
}

…

static IEnumerable<StudentScores1> ParseScores1(string inputPath)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(inputPath))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var data = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

            yield return
                new StudentScores1
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(data[0]),
                    FirstName = data[1],
                    LastName = data[2],
                    Biology = int.Parse(data[3]),
                    Chemistry = int.Parse(data[4]),
                    Physics = int.Parse(data[5]),
                    English = int.Parse(data[6]),
                    French = int.Parse(data[7]),
                    Mathematics = int.Parse(data[8])
                };
        }
    }
}

static int Average(params int[] inputs)
{
    return inputs.Sum() / inputs.Length;
}

static IEnumerable<CombinedScores> CombineScores1(
    IEnumerable<StudentScores1> scores)
{
    return scores.Select(
        s =>
        new CombinedScores
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            FirstName = s.FirstName,
            LastName = s.LastName,
            Languages = Average(s.English, s.French),
            Sciences = Average(s.Biology, s.Chemistry, s.Physics)
        });
}

static void WriteOutput(
    IEnumerable<CombinedScores> combinedScores, string outputPath)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
    {
        foreach (var scores in combinedScores)
        {
            string outputLine = string.Format(
                "{0:d3} {1} {2} {3:d3} {4:d3} {5:d3}",
                scores.Id, scores.FirstName, scores.LastName,
                scores.Languages, scores.Mathematics, scores.Sciences);

            sw.WriteLine(outputLine);
        }
    }
}
```

It's more code than you had originally, but it's safer, clearer and more maintainable. When you do all this, you realize that only `ParseScores1` and `CombineScores1` deal with the input format, so you can write `ParseScores2` that doesn't need to know anything about the output format or combining scores and also `CombineScores2`. After you do that, the main logic of your application could look like this:

```
IEnumerable<CombinedScores> scores;
if (intputFormat1)
    scores = CombineScores1(ParseScores1(inputPath));
else
    scores = CombineScores2(ParseScores2(inputPath));

WriteOutput(scores, outputPath);
```